# Take Virtual Machine ownership Vmware workstation

Tags: vmware-workstation

I have restarted my host OS without turning off VM.

Now when the system has restarted then i am not able to power on the VM as it says that VM is already in use. WHen i click take ownership then it says that VM is being used can't take ownership

What to do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guessing Lock files were left.  Remove .lck files that pertain to your vm.  Same directory as the .vmdk for the VM you're trying to use.